# Custom preference not clickable

Tags: android, android-preferences

I added a custom preference to my project (code below). I added it to my preferences xml with a custom widgetLayout:

```
<w.PlusOnePreference 
    android:title="Rate App"
    android:key="custom"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/plusone_pref"/>
```

Preference layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:focusable="false"
plus:size="standard" />
```

I see the layout and the button in the layout works fine. The only problem is that the preference isn't clickable. Like it's hidden behind something.

Any ideas on how to make it clickable?

If I add a regular Preference (without a widget layout) it works fine.

Thanks.

```
public class PlusOnePreference extends Preference {

private PlusClient mPlusClient = null; 

public PlusOnePreference(Context context) {
    super(context);

}


public PlusOnePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public PlusOnePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setPlusClient(PlusClient plusClient) {
    mPlusClient = plusClient;
}



@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);     
    //mPlusOneButton = 
    PlusOneButton plusOneButton = (PlusOneButton)view.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
    plusOneButton.initialize(mPlusClient, SettingsActivity.URL, SettingsActivity.PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
  }
```

Comment: I tried your code because I am trying to add a plus one button to my live wallpaper but it says that my preference is not a textview. I just copied your code to try it. Do you by any chance have a working example you could share for those that are trying to do the same? Thank you.

Comment: The Preference class should be updated with the new google play services, but the layout is the same..maybe start another question with your code, a preference shouldn't be a TextView anyhow...

Comment: Exactly. That's my point. My code is exactly like you have it above. Verbatim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in layout/plusone_pref.xml set android:focusable="false" for your Button

Comment: It didn't help. I added the xml of the layout.

Comment: ok this is because your button is actually ViewGroup, then setFocusable(false) for all of its children

Comment: or use this for top level container (didnt test it though) android:
descendantFocusability= "
blocksDescendants"

Comment: `android: descendantFocusability= " blocksDescendants"` worked, thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it since i proposed that just after seeing source code and didnt have a chance to test it...

Comment: If you look in `AbsListView.java` in the `onTouchEvent` handler, at the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {` block you'll see the test for focusability that it uses to decide whether to dispatch a click or not. Yet again, Android follows the principle of greatest surprise.

Answer (score 4):

Putting Pskink's answer together with Ran's comment:

- If your custom preference's layout is a `ViewGroup` (e.g. a *Layout), use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
- If it's just one `View`, use `android:focusable="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Preferences don't have a clickable attribute, though there is an `onClick()` method. Try`android:selectable`.

Comment: `androird:selectable=true` didn't help. If I put a base `Preference` in the xml then it is clickable and I get an event in `onPreferenceTreeClick`.